# Force Rails Heroku App from subdomain.herokuapp.com to apex domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

What is the proper way to send a subdomain.herokuapp.com to the apex domain of the application? This is to avoid multiple domain names with the same content.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://github.com/tylerhunt/rack-canonical-host seems to be the perfect choice for this. Leaving it here for anyone else who has the same question.

Answer (score 6):

Quoting from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

> The domain myapp.herokuapp.com will always remain active, even if
>   you’ve set up a custom domain. If you want users to use the custom
>   domain exclusively, you should send HTTP status 301 Moved Permanently
>   to tell web browsers to use the custom domain. The Host HTTP request
>   header field will show which domain the user is trying to access; send
>   a redirect if that field is myapp.herokuapp.com.

You can redirect requests to the "subdomain.herokuapp.com" using a before filter in ApplicationController or using a constraint in rails routing.

Answer (score 2):

For a comprehensive answer with some bit of extensibility, in totality it looks something like this;

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :redirect_to_example if Rails.env.production?

  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  private

    # Redirect to the appropriate domain i.e. example.com
    def redirect_to_example
      domain_to_redirect_to = 'example.com'
      domain_exceptions = ['example.com', 'www.example.com']
      should_redirect = !(domain_exceptions.include? request.host)
      new_url = "#{request.protocol}#{domain_to_redirect_to}#{request.fullpath}"
      redirect_to new_url, status: :moved_permanently if should_redirect
    end
end
```

This will redirect everything to `domain_to_redirect_to` except what's in `domain_exceptions`.

Comment: @linojon It seems to work for me on the root path, but I changed the new_url to `"#{request.protocol}#{domain_to_redirect_to}#{request.fullpath if request.fullpath != '/'}"` to avoid the trailing slash.

Comment: Just as an extra ... I didn't know about `exclude?` when I wrote this ... you could have, `should_redirect = domain_exceptions.exclude? request.host` which seems more readable.